# File Changelog Generation Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, log-files, automation, file-server

I am wondering if anyone might know a way I could set up the automatic generation of a file changelog in a directory in windows server 2012. We have a collection of word, excell, and pdf files that I am currently having to create a changelog manually on a weekly basis. I wonder if it's possible to have windows handle this process. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can be useful to show what you've done to try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Yeah, this is too broad to answer usefully.  I can say "yes," but that hardly gets you closer to solving whatever problem you're having.  What information, exactly, do you want to log?

Comment: Information to log, file name/path, date-time modified, modified by (user name)  I have not taken any steps so far to automate this process. Right now I do a date modified search of all files in the directory and look at when they were modified and update a changelog.txt file in the root of that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI.  Here is a vbscript version explaining how to use __InstanceOperationEvent from CIM_DirectoryContainsFile

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42212/WMI-and-File-System-Monitoring

This can be slow in 2008 but seems to run file in 2012

Another option is to use the filewatcher:

```
Write-Verbose ("Initializing FileSystemWatcher") -Verbose
$fileWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$fileWatcher.Path = "C:\folder"
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fileWatcher -EventName Created -SourceIdentifier File.Created -Action {
        $Global:t = $event
        Write-Host ("File/Folder Created: {0} on {1}" -f `
        $event.SourceEventArgs.Name,
        (Split-Path $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)) -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red 
        } | Out-Null
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fileWatcher -EventName Deleted -SourceIdentifier File.Deleted -Action {
        $Global:t = $event
        Write-Host ("File/Folder Deleted: {0} on {1}" -f `
        $event.SourceEventArgs.Name,
        (Split-Path $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)) -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
    } | Out-Null
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fileWatcher -EventName Changed -SourceIdentifier File.Changed -Action {
        $Global:t = $event
        Write-Host ("File/Folder Changed: {0} on {1}" -f `
        $event.SourceEventArgs.Name,
        (Split-Path $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath)) -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
    } | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Jim B's solution with WMI, but if you want something simpler with powershell:

```
Dir C:\folder -r | ? {! $_.PSIsContainer -AND $_.lastwritetime -ge '04/18/14'} > changed.txt
```

This creates a file called `changed.txt` with every file changed in `c:\folder` (and it's subdirectories) since `04/18/14`.

(credits: I got this from user nixda [here](https://superuser.com/questions/545553/list-of-recently-changed-files-for-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories))

You can add this script to your Task Scheduler to run every day.

I don't know of any way to get the information of which user changed the file. It could be done from within Word and Excel files in VBA.